# The problem with setting up IIS UrlRewrite rules for ASP.NET Core 3.1 after migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, url-rewriting, migration

I am trying to do a migration for the ASP.NET Core Web Application from 2.2 to 3.1. The frontend app for the application is `Angular`. This is the working `asp.net core 2.2` piece of code from `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    ConfigureUrlRewriting(app, env);
    ConfigureRouting(app);
}

private static void ConfigureUrlRewriting(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment() && File.Exists("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
        {
            var options = new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(reader);
            app.UseRewriter(options);
        }
    }
}

private static void ConfigureRouting(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
    {
        DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" }
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "api/{controller}/{id}");
    });
}
```

After migration to asp.net core 3.1 [following the guide from Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) the code changed like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    ConfigureUrlRewriting(app, env);
    ConfigureRouting(app);
}


private static void ConfigureUrlRewriting(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment() && File.Exists("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
        {
            var options = new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(reader);
            app.UseRewriter(options);
        }
    }
}

private static void ConfigureRouting(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
    {
        DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" }
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // Changed only the lines below
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "api/{controller}/{id}");
    });
}
```

After deploying on IIS local server there is the problem that all requests for static files returns `index.html` Here's the proof:

[image: pic1]

Here's the content of `IISUrlRewrite.xml`:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)/" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Seems like the condition `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />` is not matched for the static files. But the condition is mathed when the app is `asp.net core 2.2`

Can someone explain please this behaviour after migration? Is it the problem of `.net core` code or IIS-side problems?

Comment: You can enable [fail request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules#:~:text=If%20the%20Failed%20Request%20Tracing,module%20installer%20in%20repair%20mode.) to check the request. If the rule matches successfully and url is rewritten, maybe the issue is caused by url rewrite. Then try to disable the rule and request again.

Comment: @BruceZhang thank you for the reply. I've found a solution to the problem. I'll add the answer to the question later

Comment: @BruceZhang Unfortunately, I did not find the solution. Bruce, I've tried your steps and see that each request like `localhost/filename.js` is transformed to `localhost` (home page). Seems like the conditions with input `{REQUEST_FILENAME}` are not passed. I've also checked the `api` requests and see that condition for them works

Comment: URL matched the rewrite rule successfully so that it showed index page. So you can change the condition of rule. I don't know your specific needs and initial url, cannot provide useful suggestions.

Comment: @BruceZhang I have an angular single-page app. So all requests except api, file and directory requests should be redirected to index.html using middleware. According to other questions about url rewriting for Angular this url rewrite rule should work. But as you can see it isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I've found the answer to the question. Quote from [Microsoft docs about Url Rewrite Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware):

> The middleware doesn't support the full features of these modules.

> Some of the features of the server modules don't work with ASP.NET
> Core projects, such as the IsFile and IsDirectory constraints of the
> IIS Rewrite module. In these scenarios, use the middleware instead.

Seems like MatchType `IsFile` and `IsDirectory` are not supported by the ASP.NET Core.
So if your IIS UrlRewrite rules contains condition that using MatchType `IsFile` or `IsDirectory` you should set up url rewriting directly using IIS Url Rewrite module